# Check if a twitter username exists using ajax with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

I'm writing a piece of code that checks if what you write in a text-box is a valid username, using jQuery and Ajax I then see if this page exists - http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/value.xml - if it doesn't exist i write something like "This twitter account does not exist".

This is the code:

```
function checkname (name) {
 $.ajax({
 url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/" + name + ".xml",
 statusCode: {
 404: function() {
 $("#divOfInterest").html("Sorry, " + name + " is not a valid twitter account");}
 }
 });
}
```

But it doesn't work and i don't really know why, here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Scanu/Mx4PS/), so you can see yourself. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a php page on your server and make the request to the api using their method.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

**PHP page: (check.php)**

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=" . $_POST['name'];
    $content = @file_get_contents($url);

    if (($json_data = json_decode($content, 1)) == NULL) {
        echo 0;
    } else {
        //print_r($json_data);
        if (!empty($json_data[0]['screen_name'])) {
            // user exists
            echo 1;
        }   
    }

    exit;
}
```

**Then call it from ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataString = 'name=<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function(data){
    if (data == '1') {
        alert('user exists');
    } else {
        alert('user does not exist');
    }
    //alert(result);    
    }
});
</script>
```

**To make a request to the same page modify it this way.**

put php script at the top of your document before everything else.

```
if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {

    PHP code

    exit; // <---- this is very important
}
```

in the javascript add new variable `ajax=1`

```
var dataString = 'name=<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>&ajax=1';
```

and the url

```
url: "currentpage.php",
```

Comment: Thank you for all the reply, this seems to be the most completed :)
Since i don't want to create another php file do you if i can do the same adding this code in an existing php file
For example
if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'checkname') {
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=" . $_GET['name'] . "&include_entities=true";
echo file_get_contents($url);
}

Comment: "of course you need to change the way you handle the result other than 404 status." Sorry but i'm not so good at ajax can be more specific?

Comment: Oh sorry I am on mobile right now I will try to help u asap if no one did already.

Comment: I tried everything but can't get this to work! Php is easy but i never used ajax before and i don't know what to do

Comment: Thank you very much it works great (i changed something to fits my situation) but it is very slow! A js-only script would be faster indeed. Btw how can i add a Text when loading? for example "Checking name..." i see .ajaxSend() but i can't use it properly

Comment: when submitting the form in the function you that call `do something` before calling `$.ajax` then on success `do something else` like removing the text it says 'checking name...`. please have a look at this page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in the error console, for example in Chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/dummy.xml. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You can however build a wrapper script on your server and try to call the Twitter API from there and use your script in your AJAX call.

Comment: May you help me on this? I can make the php page but i don't know what to do with ajax :/